# Steepest ascent vector at a point of a constrained nonlinear problem

Tags: nonlinear-programming

I'm looking at this article:

- "Packing unequal circles into a strip of minimal length with a jump algorithm" (Stoyan et Yaskov, 2014) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11590-013-0646-1)

In section 5, a nonlinear **constrained** model is stated:

[image]

Then the authors write:

[image]

How does one compute this steepest ascent vector $Y^0$? If the problem were unconstrained, I would have thought of the gradient of the objective, but here I don't see

Comment: I haven't read the paywalled article, but my guess is that the authors mean the negative of the gradient of the objective function, constraints notwithstanding. However, I can;t rule out that the authors aren't referring to the negative of the gradient of the objective function projected into the nullspace of the active constraints.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone "my guess is that the authors mean the negative of the gradient of the objective function, constraints notwithstanding." what would be strange in this case is that the objective only contains variables $r$ and not $u$, and, in addition, the gradient of the objective is just $2 r_i$ for each term. "the negative of the gradient of the objective function projected into the nullspace of the active constraints." I don't understand what this means